# How do I write to excel using pandas?

Tags: excel, pandas

I have tried two methods and I keep getting an error.

My Current Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/Users/anonymous/Desktop/Version4.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter').
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Ex1')
writer.save()

I have the following error:
....   import xlsxwriter ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'
```

I also tried not having an engine and then it had the same error except the module was openpyxl. I checked to make sure in my terminal and both of them are installed.

Comment: pandas uses 3rd party modules for reading and writing excel files, as such did you try to install the dependent module as clearly stated in the error

Comment: Yes I checked and it's installed- I think the problem is it's not installed in the right location- but I don't know what that location is. I did pip install for all the modules I needed and terminal says it installed so it's just a question of where it should be placed.

Answer (score 3):

open **command script**. go to **start**, search for **cmd**, then install pip.
I was having this error, then I solve it by doing this from another solution:

`pip install xlsxwriter`

Answer (score 1):

bro,

have you tried the simple

```
pd.read_excel()
pd.to_excel()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: I think it's the same function as when I write: df.to_excel-  I just specified which sheet and what data to use in my code